Why mock is not applied on a method which called within thread after testcase finishes
I have these two classes:
one.py
class One:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        pass
        
    def startS(self):
        self._doS()

    def _doS(self):
        print("Inside doS method")
        if not self.open():
            print("The patch didn't work")
            return False

        print("The patch worked well")
        return True

    def open(self):
        print("Inside open method")
        return False

two.py
from one import One
from threading import Thread

class Two(One):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super().__init__()

    def startS(self):
        self.sThread = Thread(target=super().startS)
        self.sThread.daemon = True
        self.sThread.start()
        

I want to mock the open() method with @mock.patch('two.One.open',  mock.Mock(return_value=True)).
The patch only works if I put a sleep() in the test method. Any ideas why?
test_two.py
import unittest
from unittest import mock
from time import sleep
from two import Two 

@mock.patch('two.One.open',  mock.Mock(return_value=True))
class TestDummy(unittest.TestCase):
   
    def test_first(self) -> None:
        self.two = Two()
        self.two.startS()
        #sleep(1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()

The result without sleep:
Inside doS method
.Inside open method
The patch didn't work
Ran 1 test in 0.001s
OK

The result with sleep:
Inside doS method
The patch worked well
.
Ran 1 test in 1.002s
OK


Please create a [mcve]. You have not shown how you are running the test.

I added a reproducible example @zvone
